# Error al guardar ForeingKey con Post_save en Perfil de usuario

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Estoy creando el perfil de usuario con [post_save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/signals/), pero tengo un campo `foreign key` que no se esta guardando, y no veo forma de resolverlo. Lo hice asi:
Todo esto desde el admin de django.

> *El error es:  1048, "Column 'empresa_id' cannot be null")*

**MODELS.PY**

```
#!
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

#from django.db.models import signals
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Empresa(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    descripcion = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.nombre



TIPO_USUARIO = (
    (0, 'Administrador'),
    (1, 'Tecnico'),
    (2, 'Finanzas'),
    (3, 'Cliente'),
)


class PerfilUsuario(models.Model):  
    #DEFAULT_PK=1
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)#si es un cliente el nombre sera EJ: cliente@empresa
    empresa = models.ForeignKey(Empresa, related_name='empresa_administradores')
    #cuando se registren por default entren al grupo Admin, 
    tipo_usuario = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=TIPO_USUARIO, verbose_name="¿Que tipo de Usuario es?", default=0) 


    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'Perfil de: %s' % self.user.username


def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        PerfilUsuario.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
        print "ssssssss"
        print instance.empresa
        PerfilUsuario.empresa = instance.empresa
        PerfilUsuario.save()
post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)



class Cliente(models.Model):

    nombre_rb = models.CharField(max_length=70, verbose_name="Nombre de usuario en RB(queue, hotspot, PPPoE)")
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    # Relationship Fields
    perfil = models.OneToOneField(PerfilUsuario, )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.nombre_rb
```

**ADMIN.Py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import *
# Register your models here.

#Agrego el perfil del usuario al admin
class PerfilInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = PerfilUsuario
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'Perfil'

#Defino el nuevo UserAdmin
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (PerfilInline, )

# Se vuelve a registar UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)

class EmpresaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model=Empresa
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("nombre",)}

admin.site.register(Empresa, EmpresaAdmin)


class ClienteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model=Cliente
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("nombre_rb",)}

admin.site.register(Cliente, ClienteAdmin)
```

Por favor pueden decirme, ¿Que estoy haciendo mal en `post_save`?
Muchas gracias.

**SOLUCION:**
No era necesario ejecutar el Post_save signal, ya que estaba trabajando desde el admin. Cuando me toque crear un form en mi template, revisare si pasa este problema. De momento ya funciona. Gracias @deoxyseia

Comment: Qué es lo que sale en la parte de `print instance.empresa`?

Comment: no mostraba nada, lo puse mas arriba y de esta forma:                         print instance.perfilusuario.empresa   asi me muestra el nombre de la empresa.

Comment: No debería mostrarte el nombre de la empresa sino un objeto, es posible que lo que esté llegando no sea el objeto completo y por eso empresa_id es null.

Comment: @Deoxyseia, lo hice asi:   `empresa_usuario = Empresa.objects.get(id=instance.perfilusuario.empresa.id)
        PerfilUsuario.objects.create(user=instance, empresa=empresa_usuario, tipo_usuario=instance.perfilusuario.tipo_usuario )`   pero ahora me genera el error de  **"Duplicate entry '17' for key 'user_id'"**  que me falta?

Comment: PerfilUsuario está en relación OneToOne con User, no puedes crear otro PerfilUsuario si ya existe uno asociado a ese usuario, verifica eso en tu BD. Si quieres que un usuario tenga varios perfiles la relación debe ser ManyToOne y tu tabla perfil tener un Primary Key.

Comment: @oscar para que haces `empresa_usuario = Empresa.objects.get(id=instance.perfilusuario.empresa.id)` cuando puedes obtener la empresa simplemente con `empresa = instance.perfilusuario.empresa`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, yo se cual es tu error... si to código actualmente está asi, tienes el siguiente problema...

Esta es tu funcion actual

```
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        PerfilUsuario.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
        print "ssssssss"
        print instance.empresa
        PerfilUsuario.empresa = instance.empresa
        PerfilUsuario.save()
post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

si te das cuenta.... tu estas llamando a tu modelo `PerfilUsuario` y estas en la 3ra linea viendo si existe o no lo crea, pero no lo guardas en una variable en la memoria... simplemente lo llamaste y lo dejaste a su suerte... en la 6ta linea, haces lo mismo, le asignas a la clase una empresa, pero no lo hiciste con una instancia de la clase, obviamente en el save() arrojaria error

intenta crear instancias de tu objeto, asi:

```
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        perfil, creado = PerfilUsuario.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
        print "ssssssss"
        print instance.empresa
        perfil.empresa = instance.empresa
        perfil.save()
post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

Comment: tienes razon, me falto recibirlo con 2 elementos, como lo menciona la documentacion, retorna una tupla. Gracias German.

Comment: pudiste solucionar tu problema?

Comment: si amigo, deja marco valida tu respuesta.

Comment: Exelente aporte. "Elimine" la linea. post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User) y funciono para mi. Mi ejemplo es muy similar a la pregunta inicial.